# Bash/expect script to log in via ssh and port knocking. SSH Keys not possible

Tags: script, shell-script, expect

My login server is behind a firewall that uses port knocking to allow entry.
The login-flow is

1. Enter in port knocking command. This requires my external IP to be entered.
2. When prompted, enter in my port-knocking password.
3. Enter in ssh command
4. Enter in password

I may get permission to use ssh keys, but I am trying to write a script that will allow me to cut down on my login times, since I have to go through this flow for each shell I want to bring up.

```
#!/bin/expect
spawn fwknop -A tcp/22 -a `curl http://ipecho.net/plain` -D foo.org -P tcp -p 9999
expect "Enter encryption password:"
send "pass1\r"

spawn ssh -Y bar@foo.org
expect "bar@foo.org's password:"
send "pass2\r"
```

Running each command works fine from the command line. But when I try to run the first spawn command

```
spawn fwknop -A tcp/22 -a `curl http://ipecho.net/plain` -D foo.org -P tcp -p 9999
```

I get error:

```
fwknop: fko_set_spa_message: Error 10 - Invalid allow IP address in the SPA message data
send: spawn id exp7 not open
```

But copy/paste the same command to the command line works perfectly fine.

Comment: Is the error the same from the command line if you omit the `-a` switch (or pass it a dodgy IP)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Scott is right, expect/Tcl does not do anything special with backticks, they're just plain characters.  This should work though:

```
#!/bin/expect
set ip [exec curl http://ipecho.net/plain]
spawn fwknop -A tcp/22 -a $ip -D foo.org -P tcp -p 9999
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with `expect`, but I wonder whether **it** understands back-ticks.   Try

> `#!/bin/sh`                                #
> or specify `#!/usr/bin/env bash` if you believe that you need to.
> `` expect <<- !
>
>     spawn fwknop -A tcp/22 -a `curl http://ipecho.net/plain` -D foo.org ...
>
>     expect "Enter encryption password:"
>
>     send "pass1\r"
>
>
>
>     spawn ssh -Y bar@foo.org
>
>     expect "bar@foo.org's password:"
>
>     send "pass2\r"
>
> ! ``

so you get the `` `curl http://ipecho.net/plain` `` to be processed by the shell.